# Thread reference missing import project xamarin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I try to import Xamarin Project that i've created in Visual Studio 2015 in Xamarin Studio but i get this error:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Thread' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (MyApp)

i get this at this point:

```
public void updatePage(string id, string value)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var realm2 = Realm.GetInstance();
            var theDog = realm2.All<DBPage>().Where(d => d.id == id).First();
            realm2.Write(() => theDog.value = value.ToString());
        }).Start();
    }
```

> Compiling for Android or IOS get back the same
>
> Running on MacOS Sierra 10.12.2 and Xamarin Studio 6.1.2

Comment: Did you actually try adding the reference?

Comment: of course!  but doesn't work..

Comment: Did you add `using System.Threading` reference?

Comment: yes i use it, i tried also to clean the project but nothing

Comment: maybe i found the problem but don't know how to solve.... i want to develop for Android and iOS but not for Mac. Realm is not supported for Xamarin.Mac and maybe i've to remove some dipendences. @Cheesebaron

Comment: What type of project is this code in?

Comment: Is in portable class library project type